# How to use a action decorator for update?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to update my endpoint using a action decorator. What is better way to make a action for update?

I have two serializers:

```
class GarageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Garage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GarageSerializer
    model = Garage

class CarViewSet(RestrictedQuerysetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ('color', 'model')
    model = Car
```

I need to receive a list payload by "car" and update the "garage" by a action. I'm trying something like this:

```
class GarageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Garage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GarageSerializer
    model = Garage

    @action(detail=True, methods=['put'])
        def update_car(self, request):
            queryset = Car.objects.create()
            serializer = CarSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

My url file:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

from .views import garage


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"garage", garage.GarageViewSet, base_name="car")
router.register(r"car", garage.CarViewSet, base_name="car")

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^", include(router.urls))
]
```

payload example:

```
{
    "fuel": 2,
    "model": 2,
    "color": null,
}
```

Does anyone got an idea for an action update??

Comment: can you add your `urls.py` file?

Comment: Hello, @JPG I just added my url example. Thank you!

Comment: Check my answer though

Comment: Pls add the complete urls.py file

Comment: @JPG Ok. I updated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, correct your indentation,

```
class GarageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Garage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GarageSerializer
    model = Garage

    @action(detail=True, methods=['put'])
    def update_car(self, request):
        queryset = Car.objects.create()
        serializer = CarSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

then, add the view class into your `urls.py` as,

```
path('path/to/your/put/operation/', GarageViewSet.as_view({"put": "update_car"}), name='any-name-you-like'),
```

#### Update-1

```
#urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

from .views import garage

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"garage", garage.GarageViewSet, base_name="car")
router.register(r"car", garage.CarViewSet, base_name="car")

urlpatterns = [
                  path('garage/<int:pk>/update-card/', GarageViewSet.as_view({"put": "update_car"}), name='any-name-you-like'),
              ] + router.urls
```

Comment: Hey @JPG. I put my url example. When I try put your example (with .as_view...) I receive this erro: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'`

Comment: same error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'`